Layout of the standard AddProducts button from Pricebook
I have a question that I have never been able to resolve, how can I change the fields that appear when I press the AddProduct button:

When you click on it, these fields appear as columns:
x
I am aware that these fields are configured in the search layout:

The problem is that when I go to the next screen, I want the custom fields that I created in pricebook entry to appear but I don't know where to configure them.

suggestions? Thanks in advance

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385573&type=1

but this is for opportunity, i need for pricebook and pricebook related list is not customizable

May I know what org is this?, looks so different, than the ones I am working with

It's a completely new org, Education Cloud, it has implemented the new lightning view that is more user-friendly but I'm not completely convinced. Maybe that's what seems strange to you, right? Here's a video where it explains it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9jE_T30S4s
